# multiplying column values in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following query:

```sql
SELECT RTRIM(TO_CHAR('dst.' || per_growth,
                     'FM9G999G999G999G999G990D99999999999',
                     ' NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' '),
             ',')
  FROM dst__d_data dst;
```

I have concatenated ***per_growth*** column label with the ***`dst.`***

Now, what I want is **`'dst.' || per_growth * 0.01`**. However, it is rising error message:

> **ORA-01722**: invalid number

How can I carry out multiplication in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Your existing query will raise the same error. You can't concatenate first, and then apply `TO_CHAR`; `TO_CHAR` expects a number, not a string. First convert the number to string, and then concatenate `'dst.'` to the result of `TO_CHAR`.

After you fix this first mistake (even for your existing query), multiplying by 0.01 in the argument to `TO_CHAR` should not cause any kind of new problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```sql
SELECT 'dst.'||.01 * TO_NUMBER( per_growth, 
                               'FM9G999G999G999G999G990D99999999999', 
                               'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS = '',.'' ')
  FROM dst__d_data;
```

prefix some string stuff after finishing the numerical conversion with **`'',.''`** pattern(as the data seems to have comma as decimal seperator) and multiplication operation

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=af078f8382f07629124521bc181dc187)</kbd>

Comment: I think I put the question a little wrong. Multiplication should be done for each value of column dst.per_growth(it should not add dst. value to each row).

Comment: `per_growth` appears to be a number, not a string. The OP applies `to_char` to it to convert to string (in an incorrect way, but that seems to be the intent).

Comment: yes, eg. I needed to change the provided value for the column within the demo, and did it, thanks @mathguy